# Primefaces Dialog box - show it conditionally. javascript code not working

Tags: primefaces, spring-webflow-2

I want to show a dialog box on the click of a primefaces commandbutton. Before the dialog box , I need to check a condtional.

I am using Spring web-flow 2.3.0.

So I am doing it like this ,

And the Dialog Box is

I am not able to show this dialog box based on this condition.

Please help me ,any pointers?

**SWF 2.3.0 Primefaces 2.2.1 JSF 2 Spring Security 3 Spring 3.1.0M1I EhCache Apache Tomcat 6.0 STS 2.5.1**

So I have changed my code as per below

```
                    <p:commandLink id="addRequest" immediate="true" value="addreq"
                    oncomplete="dlg3.show()" update="dialogPanel">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                        value="#{searchHandler.selectedAccIns}"
                        target="#{reqSearchHandler.checkAccStatus}" />
                </p:commandLink>
```

And the dialog box is

```
                <p:outputPanel id="dialogPanel"
                rendered="#{not reqSearchHandler.accStatusFlag}">
                <p:dialog header="Effect Dialog" widgetVar="dlg3"
                    showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" height="200">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="Account is #{searchHandler.selectedAccIns.accStatusDesc}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Do you want to continue?" />
                    <div align="left">
                        <p:commandButton value="Yes" action="accept" />
                        <p:spacer width="960" height="5" />
                        <p:commandButton value="No" action="cancel" />
                    </div>
                </p:dialog>
            </p:outputPanel>
```

But when I am clicking on the command link , I am getting 3 dialog boxes. Can you please tell me why it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody else just posted the same problem! :)

You should use the `oncomplete` attribute instead of `onclick` of the commandButton. The click javascript event occurs before the page posts back, likely causing your dialog not to appear because of the page reloading.

`oncomplete="dlg3.show()"` will display the dialog AFTER the postback.

Comment: This seems like a completely different problem now.  In the future please create a new question for a new problem.

Comment: @Suman, This is a problem with Primefaces dialogs when you have them within the same form as other elements that asynchronously post back.  Try placing your dialog in a seperate form and set `appendToBody="true"` property of the dialog and this problem should be fixed.