# conditionally show Primefaces dialog box

Tags: primefaces

In reference to the query that I have posted
[Primefaces Dialog box - show it conditionally. javascript code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281605/primefaces-dialog-box-show-it-conditionally-javascript-code-not-working)

The problem is that when

```
<p:outputPanel id="dialogPanel"
            rendered="#{not reqSearchHandler.accStatusFlag}">
```

is not rendered as rendered turns out to be FALSE , then when I click on the commandbutton , its keep on clocking and I am not able to go the next page , it seems that ajax request is never getting completed as oncomplete="dlg3.show()" needs dialog box in the page.As rendered turns out to be false , it never finds dlg3.

```
<p:commandLink id="addRequest" immediate="true" value="addreq"
                oncomplete="dlg3.show()" update="dialogPanel">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener
                    value="#{searchHandler.selectedAccIns}"
                    target="#{reqSearchHandler.checkAccStatus}" />
            </p:commandLink>
```

Can somebody please help me how to avoid opening dialog box when a particular condition is false. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is the dlg3 inside of dialogPanel? Why don't you post the complete code?
If so, then just  before calling dlg3.show)(), change the *rendered condition* to true (e.g. by adding action listener) or just move the dialog outside the panel.

Comment: Requirement is that I have a status Flag , if it is TRUE , then I do not have to show the dialog box , but if it is false then I have to show this dialog box - and all this I have to do when I click on the commandbutton.On removing the outputpanel, dialogbox always showed up.Any idea?

Comment: Like I said you should set status flag to true, update your dialogPanel and then call dlg3.show()

Comment: Use visible option of dialog to auto display.

Comment: Gotta listen to what PF creator says =)

Comment: Using Visible is working fine.But when Visible = "True" , it is showing the dialog box with clicking commandbutton which I dont think is the the right way. Also , when Visible = False and I click on the commandbutton , it is showing the dialog box which should not be happening.